# Using tf.train.Feature and tf.train.Example with ragged tensors

Tags: tensorflow

How can we use `tf.train.Feature` and `tf.train.Example` to save Ragged Tensors to TFRecords?

I have this piece of code:

```
d = [[], [1, 3], [5]]
d_tf = tf.ragged.constant(d)
```

How can I write it to TFRecords along with other regular tensors?

Normally I do something like:

```
feature = {"feat_name": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=feat_val))}
examples = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
examples.SerializeToString()
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @eng2019, please refer to this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#tfexample) from the official website of tensorflow for a detailed explanation. Thank you!